# How to display the property of a file opened by fopen in php?

Tags: php

I want to get the values of properties associated with a file, I have pdf file as `test.pdf` in my desktop and I want to display its Type, Name, Size and others properties using PHP code as follows.

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("C:/Users/Rink16/Desktop/test.pdf","r") or die("Unable to open file!");

//i want to echo the variables such as echo test name,
// its size, its type using PHP

?>
```

Please help..

Comment: You are giving `fopen` the file, so you already have the name and type.
If you want the file size : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.filesize.php

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _type_ since in your example you show test.pdf which type is well...a PDF. Getting file size and other information you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php

Comment: is something can i do with `$myfile` so that i can direct print the `test` and type `pdf`

Comment: Check this one.  I think you can get idea about how you need to get property details from file.

FYR  :- https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-files-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a lot of information using [SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

```php
$myfile = new SplFileInfo("C:/Users/Rink16/Desktop/test.pdf");

echo $myfile->getSize() . PHP_EOL;
echo $myfile->getExtension() . PHP_EOL;
echo $myfile->isDir() . PHP_EOL;
```